# Will damp smell go if you don’t wash carpet?

Tags: smell

Note I have already found the source and fixed it hence no more condensation,  I am just wondering if the smell in the carpet will go without washing.

Car carpet smells damp but not musky yet.  I was trying to remove the carpet but In the process I managed to squish out quite a bit of water.  Still smells wet( maybe that means damp) however if I I don’t see puddles and much of the water is out.

If I no longer see condensation develop on the windows does that mean I can leave carpet in car and it will dry itself out over time since most moisture has been removed?

If yes, as it dries, can I expect the damp Damp smell to go over time too I.e. no need to remove and clean?  Like I say it’s not musky or moody and I’m guessing the f their is no condensation on windows it isn’t gonna get worse and will dry and Remove be the remaining smell over time?

Comment: Only real solution is to replace the carpets.

Comment: I have a car with damp carpets in the hatchback floor area, and the car smells musty because of it. Until I find where the leak is (possibly around one of the rear lighting units) there is no point doing much except ventilating the car when possible. When parked up, the window glass condenses inside due to the damp.

Answer (score 0):

Condensation on the windows is an indicator, but your carpets can still be damp without it. You don't absolutely have to remove the carpets, you can soak a lot of the water with lots of towels, you can put a dehumidifier in it as well. Driving is good, provided you ventilate the car well as you do, windows open and heating on if it is cold.

Of course, fixing the source of the leak should be your first priority, otherwise you'll never get rid of the moisture and you **will** have to replace the carpet.